# How do I load.vtt file into the video thumbnails(Imageview) in my videoview android?

Tags: android, webvtt, vtt

I've saved that file locally, but I'm not sure how to load it.

my .vtt file have data like below :-

```
    WEBVTT 00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:05.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=0,0,160,90

00:00:05.000 --> 00:00:10.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=160,0,160,90

00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:15.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=320,0,160,90

00:00:15.000 --> 00:00:20.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=480,0,160,90

00:00:20.000 --> 00:00:25.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=640,0,160,90

00:00:25.000 --> 00:00:30.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=0,90,160,90

00:00:30.000 --> 00:00:35.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=160,90,160,90

00:00:35.000 --> 00:00:40.000
/xxxxx/xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx.webp#xywh=320,90,160,90
```

I finds a lot in stack but i am not getting any .vtt related answer for android videoview

When I drag in videoview Android, I want thumbnails to appear on the frame like below

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking doesn't make any sense.

`VideoView` plays video files. The supported formats are given here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

A `VTT` file is a just a text file. It contains *supplementary information* about a video such as subtitles, captions, descriptions, chapters, etc.

VTT files do not contain any video data.

That is the reason you are "not getting any .vtt related answer for android videoview" - because it VTT isn't a video file and `VideoView` doesn't support it.